# Most efficient way to assign a list of elements into dataframe columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of terms that I've accomplished through a split (`split = str_split(terms, "//")`), where each element would be a row, and within each element the values of three different columns appear sequentially:

```
split

[[1]]
[1] "value_col_1_1" "value_col_2_1" "value_col_3_1"

[[2]]
[1] "value_col_1_2" "value_col_2_2" "value_col_3_2"
```

I would like to assign each of the values to columns in a dataframe. My first idea was a for loop, but it looks like it is quite inefficient, since it is taking longer than a similar code to accomplish the same task. The loop is the following:

```
for (row in 1:length(new_categorization)){
    df[row, "first_col"] <- split[[row]][1]
    df[row, "second_col"] <- split[[row]][2]
    df[row, "third_col"] <- split[[row]][3]
  }
```

What is the most time efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do.call(rbind, split)` to get the vectors into a matrix row-wise. Just convert that to a data frame and name as appropriate. Here's a full reprex:

```r
do.call(rbind, split) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(paste0(c('first', 'second', 'third'), '_col'))
#>       first_col    second_col     third_col
#> 1 value_col_1_1 value_col_2_1 value_col_3_1
#> 2 value_col_1_2 value_col_2_2 value_col_3_2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
split <- list(c("value_col_1_1", "value_col_2_1", "value_col_3_1"),
              c("value_col_1_2", "value_col_2_2", "value_col_3_2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse way would be to use `transpose()` and `map(unlist)`. If the list is unnamed we still need `set_names` and can then create the columns by splicing `tibble(!!! .)`.

However, Allan's base R way is simpler.

```r
library(tidyverse)

split <- list(c("value_col_1_1", "value_col_2_1","value_col_3_1"),
              c("value_col_1_2", "value_col_2_2", "value_col_3_2"))

split %>% 
  transpose %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  set_names(., paste0(c("first", "second", "third"), "_col")) %>%
  tibble(!!! . )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   first_col     second_col    third_col    
#>   <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
#> 1 value_col_1_1 value_col_2_1 value_col_3_1
#> 2 value_col_1_2 value_col_2_2 value_col_3_2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like already a vectorized solution like the following is orders of magnitude faster:

```
df["first_col"] <- sapply(split, function(x) x[1])
df["second_col"] <- sapply(split, function(x) x[2])
df["third_col"] <- sapply(split, function(x) x[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

data.table package has a function `transpose` to efficiently transpose a list. You can use it and then call setDF on the resulting list to obtain a data.frame.

```
library(data.table)

df = transpose(split) |> 
  setDF() |> 
  setnames(paste0(c("first", "second", "third"), "_col"))

      first_col    second_col     third_col
1 value_col_1_1 value_col_2_1 value_col_3_1
2 value_col_1_2 value_col_2_2 value_col_3_2
```

Using build-in functions

```
df = split |> 
  simplify2array() |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(paste0(c("first", "second", "third"), "_col"))

      first_col    second_col     third_col
1 value_col_1_1 value_col_2_1 value_col_3_1
2 value_col_1_2 value_col_2_2 value_col_3_2
```